# ajax dynamic load not showing all results strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm doing a simple blog with php and mysql. So far so good. But i want to load the posts dynamically on one page when i scroll down. It works, but not completely.
I'm fairly average using javascript/jquery, ajax and such..

Results are loading on the index page, but not all results displays.. i have ten rows and only *1,3,4,5,7,8,9* shows up in results. Row number *2, 6 and 10* does not.. i cannot understand this strange behaviour..

My code below:

**index.php**

```html
<script src="assets/js/load_data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="results">
<?php include_once('result_data.php'); ?>
</div>
<div id="loader"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
<span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div>
```

**result_data.php**

```
$perPage = 4;
$sql_query = "SELECT blog_posts.id
        ,blog_posts.post_title
        ,blog_posts.post_content
        ,blog_posts.post_date
        ,blog_posts.post_category
        ,blog_posts.post_author
        ,blog_posts.slug
        ,blog_categories.cat_id
        ,blog_categories.cat_name
        ,blog_categories.cat_slug
    FROM blog_posts
    LEFT JOIN blog_categories ON blog_posts.post_category = blog_categories.cat_id
    ORDER BY blog_posts.id DESC;"
$page = 1;
if(!empty($_GET["page"])) {
$page = $_GET["page"];
}
$start = ($page-1)*$perPage;
if($start < 0) $start = 0;
$query = $sql_query . " LIMIT " . $start . "," . $perPage;

$resultset = $conn->prepare($query);
$resultset->execute();
$records = $resultset->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(empty($_GET["total_record"])) {
$_GET["total_record"] = $resultset->rowCount();

}

$output = '';
if(!empty($records)) {
$output .= '<input type="hidden" class="page_number" value="' . $page . '" />';
$output .= '<input type="hidden" class="total_record" value="' . $_GET["total_record"] . '" />';
while ($row = $resultset->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$output .= '
<div class="blog-post">
<div class="blog-post-header"><h2><a href="/'.$row['slug'].'">'.$row['post_title'].'</a></h2></div> 
<div class="blog-post-info"><p class="muted">'.strftime("%A, %e %B %Y, %H:%M", $row['post_date']).'</p>
</div> 
<div class="blog-post-short">'.$row['post_content'].'
</div>
<div class="blog-post-footer">Kategori <a href="?category='.$row['cat_slug'].'">'.$row['cat_name'].'</a> av <a href="?author='.$row['post_author'].'">'.$row['post_author'].'</a></div>
</div>';
}
}
echo $output;
```

**load_data.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
if($(".page_number:last").val() <= $(".total_record").val()) {
var pagenum = parseInt($(".page_number:last").val()) + 1;
loadRecord('result_data.php?page='+pagenum);
}
}
});
});
function loadRecord(url) {
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: "GET",
data: {total_record:$("#total_record").val()},
beforeSend: function(){
$('#loader').show();
},
complete: function(){
$('#loader').hide();
},
success: function(data){
$("#results").append(data);
},
error: function(){}
});
}
```

**A huge thanks in advance!**

**UPDATE #1**
If i change the $perPage from 4 to a higher value than i have records in the database e.g 15, it displays all results!
So i have narrowed it down to the LIMIT OFFSET part where the bugging occurs.

**UPDATE #2**
The previous update statement was not entirely correct, if i change the $perPage value, MORE results are shown, but not all!
Also i have run the SQL commands manually and they work flawlessly. So the problem lies not within the SQL statement.

**UPDATE #3**
I give up.. Went with a classic pagination and found this (https://infiniteajaxscroll.com/) awesome plugin, works flawless!

Comment: If i edit result_data.php file to fetch sql data ASC instead of DESC 2,3,4,6,7,8,10 only show... = 1,5,9 are missing then..

Comment: You call fetch outside of the while loop. That'll "consume" a row as if it wasn't there. The "bad" call: `$records = $resultset->fetch(PDO::F...` If you have a local development environment,  spwnd some time setting up remote debugging with xdebug. It lets you put breakpoints in your code so you can what the values of variables are and what flow of execution is, exactly. And it's free!

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but shouldn't the query be:
`$query = $sql_query . " OFFSET " . $start . " LIMIT " .  $perPage`

Comment: Terminus: I'm not sure which while you're talking about. And not sure if i understand why "one would be consumed" here. But i will try look into xdebug. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @abhinav What would the purpose of this be? What result would you be expecting? Asking honestly since i can't see how this resolves my issue.

Comment: @abhinav I was tired when i read your comment by the way! You are right and wrong. using "value, value" is just a shorter syntax for "OFFSET value LIMIT value" as you suggested. :)

Comment: And @Terminus i have narrowed it down to being the LIMIT OFFSET equations where the bugging occurs.. But have not yet figured it out though..

Comment: @Slckr Okay. I didn't know about the shorter syntax. Have you tried running the query in MySql console itself? Does the bug occur there also?

Comment: @abhinav No worries. And yes i have tried the SQL code itself, and manually incremented it the way my code is supposed to do, and then it works flawlessly.. So the approach is right, the code is buggy ^^

Comment: @Slckr Okay. So in your loadRecord function you are fetching total_records value by doing `data: {total_record:$("#total_record").val()},` where as total_record is the class name as returned by your Php script. Can you check whether something funny is happening due to that?

Comment: @abhinav I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot the javascript tbh..

Comment: I stumbled across a third solution to my problems in another stackoverflow question.. https://infiniteajaxscroll.com/ Worked flawlessly!